# POI: CTStylesheet refers to the missing type CTColors

Tags: apache-poi

I am using the XSSF part of poi-3.9 (downloaded from project website) in my project.

Recently I needed to read the content of the StyleSource of a 2007 excel file (`xl/styles.xml`).

For that I tried to do the following:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fis));       

CTStylesheet st = wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet();

CTColors colors = st.getColors();
```

The compiler would then tell me that `CTStylesheet refers to the missing type CTColors`.

And as a matter of facts the Class `CTColors` is referenced by the class `CTStyleSheet`, but there is no such class in the appropriate jar file delivered with the poi-3.9 zip file.

Please note the difference between `CTColor` (which exists in the `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar file) and `CTColors` which doesn't exist.

```
// Method descriptor #82 ()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTColors;
public abstract org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTColors getColors();
```

Am I missing any kind of dependency there?

I looked through all jars delivered with the poi-3.9 zip file and couldn't find the `CTColors` (plural) class.

I also verified the case in the last release 3.10 beta2 and the problem seems to persist.

How should I proceed to read the colors from `xl/styles.xml`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `poi-ooxml-schemas.jar` [only contains a subset of the ooxml xmlbeans classes](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), you'll need to additionally reference the [`ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar)

Comment: For a long term fix, if you submit a unit test to Apache POI which includes the use of CTColors, then future versions of the `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar will include it. (Unit Tests are used to identify the "common" parts to include)